# Was bedeutet der Begriff "im Sturm erobern"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Was ist die Bedeutung des Begriff "etw. im Sturm erobern" oder "etw. im Sturm nehmen"?

Answer (score 3):

[Sturm](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sturm_Wind) meint in diesem Fall kein Wetterereignis, sondern eine Art des militärischen Angriffs:

> heftiger, schnell vorgetragener Angriff mit dem Ziel, den [völlig unvorbereiteten] Gegner zu überraschen, seine Verteidigung zu durchbrechen

Historische Beispiele sind etwa der [Sturm auf die Bastille](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_auf_die_Bastille) oder der [Sturm auf Freiburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_auf_Freiburg). Heute wird "Sturm" in dieser Bedeutung meistens im übertragenen Sinne verwendet. Man spricht beispielsweise vom "Sturm aufs kalte Büfett".

"Im Sturm" meint schlicht, dass etwas in der Art eines militärischen Sturms getan wird. Wenn man also beispielsweise das Herz einer Person "im Sturm erobert", tut man das sehr schnell, sehr heftig und ohne große Gegenwehr.

Wichtig dabei ist, dass bei diesen übertragenen Verwendungen meistens keine Gewalt oder Übergriffigkeit im Spiel ist. Beim erwähnten Beispiel "jemandes Herz im Sturm erobern" hat die Person, deren Herz erobert wird, meistens nichts dagegen einzuwenden. Je nach Kinderstube der beteiligten Personen kann das beim "Sturm aufs kalte Büfett" jedoch anders aussehen ;)